# My facebook authentication is not working?

Tags: python, facebook

I changed my domain from `abc.com` to `xyz.com`. After that my `facebook authentication` is not working.

It is throwing a key error `KeyError: 'access_token'`I am using python as my language.

Comment: Guess: is the facebook API key tied to the domain? Do you need to go to Facebook and either update the domain registered with your app there or request a new API key for the new domain?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update the domain in the facebook settings/api key which allow you access.